# Total number of likes on views images and social networking?

Tags: views

I have a view that displays 8 images (which links to their particular node) uploaded by the all users. Now I want to display a counter which counts total number of likes on that post either by facebook or on the site.

Can I link the image like with the facebook likes of that particular image post?

Answer (score 0):

To count how many times users have liked a particular node maybe checkout the [Like Button](https://drupal.org/project/likebtn) module.